# PHP - How to cater for timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have setup a web app for a client. The server is in US I believe. The client himself is in Sydney.

He says he added a record to a table with a timestamp field and it shows the timestamp as `2010-11-19 07:12:00` but the actual local time has been `2010-11-20 13:12:00`.
So he is `30 hours` ahead of the time recorded. *This doesn't look right*, how could the offset be greater than 24 hours? And what should I change/use so he sees correct date/time?

Edit:
Would it be correct approach to add 30 hours to current time before inserting the record?

Comment: The time change from one timezone to another can be greater than 24 hours: the actual timezones range from GMT+12 to GMT-14. The overlap (GMT-13 and GMT-14) is the pacific island nation of Kiribati, which straddles the +-180 meridian. Naturally, they keep the same date throughout the country, so the International Date Line juts out to the east to not divide the nation into two days. However, as you noted, there is no combination of time zones that would give a 30 hour delta.

Comment: @David Yaw - Very interesting information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to check the time on the server. Make sure that is correct.

To fix the issue, you have to know the offset for the user, so this will either need to be a recorded in a user profile, or if it is stationary for the whole application, you can set the server's time to correspond with his timezone.

Another option is using PHP's [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Another option would be to use certain [Timezone Setting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) PHP offers.

A final option would be to set the [timezone setting for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) this requires you to add items to the startup options, so you will need to edit the startup script for MySQL.

Comment: Thank you. This is shared hosting and timezone setting for MySQL could not be altered. As Mike Baranczak also noted this is most likely a two fold problem of which I could correct only one. So I should either hard-code the offset by adding it to current time literally, or try to correct timezone AND hope support will correct the other culprit.

Answer (score 1):

If the offset is 30 hours, then the culprit can't possibly be the time zone. Or at least, it can't be the *only* culprit. Without more details, that's the best I can do.

Comment: My preferred approach is to store everything in GMT. If you have to show the timestamp in a human-readable formay

Answer (score 1):

Sydney, Australia is GMT+10. The east coast of the US is GMT-5. That's a 15 hour difference.

Could be a coding error, where the timezone is getting corrected twice.

Comment: Good catch on the possibility of applying a 15 hour offset twice, that would give us exactly 30 hours. But I am not touching the timezone currently. What's your take; could `not caring for timezone` on its own also create this effect?